# How can I convert a string containing object paths and values to an object?

Tags: javascript, redis

I want to convert strings of the form `'a|b|c', val1` and `'a|d', val2` to a nested object of the form `{a: {b : {c : 'val1'}, d: 'val2'}}`. I tried the following -

```
const path2Obj = (path, value) => {
  const obj = {};
  const pathComps = path.split('|').reverse();
  pathComps.forEach((comp, ind) => {
    if (ind) {
      obj[comp] = obj;
    } else {
      obj[comp] = value;
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
console.log(path2Obj('a|b|c', 'val1'));
```

but it logs `<ref *1> { c: 'val1', b: [Circular *1], a: [Circular *1] }`. Any ideas?

### Background to my question

I am storing nested objects whose structure is not known before runtime to a [redis](https://redis.io) database. Redis does not appear to support nested objects natively so I first convert the them to path / value pairs of strings and save them as [hashes](https://redis.io/docs/manual/data-types/#hashes). This works but I need a way to convert them back to objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically use `reduce`, iterate over the path array which you created with `split` and then either return the value from the object if it exists, otherwise add value (new nested object or value param).

```js
const obj = {}

const path2Obj = (path, value, obj) => {
  path.split('|').reduce((r, e, i, arr) => {
    return r[e] || (r[e] = i === arr.length - 1 ? value : {})
  }, obj)
};

path2Obj('a|b|c', 'val1', obj)
path2Obj('a|d', 'val2', obj)

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: your solution is elegant but I struggle to understand how it works. When the last path component is reached `i === arr.length - 1`, why assign `value : {}` to `r[e]`?

Comment: @user2309803 Is this maybe easier to understand https://jsfiddle.net/75aou6vs/ ?

Comment: I have [added some `console.log` debugging messages](https://jsfiddle.net/f9eL83qg/1/) to your jsfiddle, The reducer callback only seems to return `{}` (see `returning r[e]` log messages) and `value`. Consequently the accumulator `r` is always `{}`. This is different from the [MDN canonical example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#examples). How does your fiddle build the resulting nested object?