# How does Array.prototype.reduce() update initialValue via previousValue?

Tags: javascript

I found a way to build objects dynamically from text paths. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71786452/how-can-i-convert-a-string-containing-object-paths-and-values-to-an-object) relies on the reducer passed to [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#syntax) updating `initialValue` parameter via `previousValue` callback parameter. Here is a simplified example -

```
const initialValue = {};
['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  previousValue[currentValue] = {};
  return previousValue[currentValue];
}, initialValue);
console.log(initialValue); //{ a: { b: { c: {} } } }
```

Apparently the inner most `{}` of `initialValue` is replaced with `{ currentValue: {}}` on each iteration. Where is this behaviour defined? In case it is not defined, how else could an object be built based on text paths?

Comment: It could just as easily be a `for` loop, there's nothing specific to reduce that makes this work except that it handles tracking the `previousValue` implicilty.

Comment: Isn't an object's keys strings? Is that what you mean by textpaths?

Comment: Objects are only references in JavaScript, therefore the initial value `obj` does not remain fixed in your iteration (step by step, you are adding inner members). Just start with a fresh `{}` as initial value to avoid this effect.

Comment: You'll note the accepted answer in the duplicate shows both your reduce solution as well as an implementation with just a `for` loop (as well as building it from inside out with `reduceRight`)

Comment: @zer00ne I mean property paths as used in https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#toPath